# Custom control without Adapter. Binding List

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I created a Custom Control for monodroid. Following the tutorial [N-20 CustomControl](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-20-CustomControls3) and this [MvxListView](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs?source=c) because my control binding a IEnumerable. 
My control inherits to FrameLayout, then I don't have access to Adapter property from Parent Class.

When I assign the List binding property and call the RaisePropertyChanged event. Doesn't raise up. How can  I do that?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit to show code**

Talk is cheap, I Show the code.

This is the header of custom control and the list of binding.

```
    public class DrawingBoardControl : View
    {        

    private DrawingItems m_drawingItems;

    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public DrawingItems CanvasItems
    {
        get
        {
            return m_drawingItems;
        }

        set
        {
            m_drawingItems = value;
            this.Update();
        }
    }
    ...
```

I use a class called "DrawingItems", there are

```
    public class DrawingItems : IEnumerable<IDrawingElement>
    {
    private List<IDrawingElement> myDrawingItems = new List<IDrawingElement>();

    public IEnumerator<IDrawingElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myDrawingItems.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(IDrawingElement element)
    {
        myDrawingItems.Add(element);
    }
  }
```

However, in other custom controls I use a IEnumerable and generic List and the problem persist.

When, I use RaisePropertyChanged in my ViewModel, the Items property don't raise.

Sorry for not include more information yesterday

Comment: This question is too hard to answer. It needs a bit more information. Perhaps some code might help - e.g. of the bound View property, the bound ViewModel property and of the binding itself. Some debug trace might also help - this might tell you what is or isn't going wrong.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean with "doesn't raise up". BTW this code is only for your last question? My first answer is about your first question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are always some answers for uncomplete questions:

If you cannot access the Adapter of the parent, the parent has to set the context of the child. There are no more options. Make your custom control fully bindable by exposing the complete interfaces. The list has to provide the context for the list items.

Somehow a customcontrol binding to a IEnumerable feels very wrong. A custom control for displaying a list item, I can understand, but not for a list. But of course it can be done. But you end up setting references to the container class en setting the datacontext or viewmodel of each item.

But please provide more info if you want others to help.

UPDATE:
Then I also update :) This provides some clues of the problem:

Don't assign a new list, but inherit the this from ObservableCollection, or manually call the raiseProperty with the correct parameters in the setter. I think it is by design assigning a new list will not call PropertyRaised.

As the 'App is King'-rule: in this case I notify the propertychanged myself. It might have something to do with the weak references problem (see the attribute on the ListItem property).